# Search Associated models rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord

I currently have a search form that searches through columns in my recipe model, I now want to search through an associated model aswell called country, and search the name column

So my code so far is

```
  q = "%#{params[:search]}%"

 @countrysearch = Recipe.where("dish_name LIKE ? OR country_of_origin LIKE ? OR difficulty LIKE ? OR preperation_time LIKE?", q, q, q, q )
```

Am i correct in saying that I will need to do a join on the country model? if so I am unsure of the syntax for this, does anyone know which resources to look at or have performed this query before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use joins, or eager load the associations and specify conditions on it:

```
Recipe.includes(:country).where("dish_name like ? OR countries.name like ?", ...)
```

See the section "Specifying conditions on eager loaded associations" in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations).

Comment: thanks for answer.can i ask why it is countries.name rather than country.name?

Comment: Because it's based on the table name, which by default is plural. If your table is named something else, you'd have to edit accordingly. The reason that it's there in the first place is to avoid an error in case there's more than one `name` field in your joined tables.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem named ransack https://github.com/ernie/ransack supossed to allow this ( https://github.com/ernie/ransack#has_many-and-belongs_to-associations )